# "No such file or directory" when executing Perl script

Tags: iphone, perl, terminal, vuforia

I have a 3D modal for cup.obj. I need to convert to .h file so I downloaded this http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/ And put cup.obj file to this folder. Then I run from terminal obj2opengl.pl cup.obj I didn't get .h file.

```
Ranganatha-GVs-Mac-mini:~ ranganathagv$ ./obj2opengl.pl cup.obj
-bash: ./obj2opengl.pl: No such file or directory
Ranganatha-GVs-Mac-mini:~ ranganathagv$
```

Comment: Where did `obj2opengl.pl` download to? Are you running that command from the same directory?

Comment: I download from http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/

Comment: Where did it download TO? Is it on your desktop? You need to change to this directory before running the command, e.g: `cd ~/Desktop/`

Answer (score 1):

The `obj2opengl.pl` script probably hasn't the right permission set in order to be executable using the `./` syntax.

Two choices here, you can either:

- Change the permission on the script using `chmod +x obj2opengl.pl`, and using `./obj2opengl.pl cup.obj` should work from there on, or
- Run the script using `perl obj2opengl.pl cup.obj`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That would give: `bash: ./obj2opengl.pl: Permission denied`